# Javascript conditional formatting not recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm having a jQuery DataTable that is generated from a JSON file. All works fine, but as it comes to conditional formatting, I get stuck. The following script gives all cells in column 2 a 'positive' class (even negative integers). What's wrong with my if-statement?

```
 "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
      if ( parseFloat(aData[1]) <= 0 ) {
         jQuery('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass('negative');
      } else {
         jQuery('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass('positive');
      }
      return nRow;
}
```

thanks in advance!

edit: a part of the JSON file (the number I'm referring to is "punten":

```
[
    {
        "spel_id": "2012-09-24 15:43:56",
        "locatie": "white room",
        "speler": "Arne",
        "punten": "17"
    },
   {
        "spel_id": "2012-09-24 15:43:56",
        "locatie": "white room",
        "speler": "Bjorg",
        "punten": "26"
    }
]
```

and my js to generate the table (using DataTables):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sAjaxSource": "json_gespeeldekaartings.php",
            "aoColumns": [
              { "mData": "kaarting"},
              { "mData": "speler" },
              { "mData": "punten"}
            ],
            "sAjaxDataProp": "",
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [],
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if ( parseFloat(aData[1]) <= 0 ) {
                    jQuery('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass('negative');
                } else {
                    jQuery('td:eq(1)', nRow).addClass('positive');
                }
                return nRow;
                }
            } )
        } );
```

Comment: Can you provide more code (including the JSON) ?

Comment: What does `console.log(aData[1])` print to the console?

Comment: One advice use [mRender](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns#mRender) for that purpose, insted of fnRowCallback.

Comment: Johan: ReferenceError: aData is not defined

Comment: @ loncar : and how would that have to embedded in my current code? I'm an absolute newbie with js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inster of

```
if ( parseFloat(aData[1]) <= 0 ) {
```

use

```
if ( parseFloat(aData.punten <= 0 )
```

**EDIT**
try this :

remove fnRowCallback and use mRender for in this example :

```
...
"aoColumns": [
              { "mData": "kaarting"},
              { "mData": "speler" },
              { "mData": "punten",
                "sType": "numeric",
                "mRender":  function ( data, type, full ) {
                      if(data > 0) return "<div class='positive'>" + data + "</div>"; // example
                      return "<div class='negative'>" + data + "</div>";              // example
                 }
              }
            ],
...
```

Comment: the problem remains the same :(

Comment: try alert(aData.punten) or console.log(aData.punten) to se if it gets ok number?

Comment: ReferenceError: aData is not defined

Comment: take a look at my post, I have added mRender usage.

Comment: ok, thanks! we're getting there :). Now every single number is replaced by "negative" or "positive", it should add the class to it.

Comment: small additional question to this: now I add a div inside the cell, is it possible to somehow set the td-class instead of adding a div into the cell?